# XML Sitemap - Google - Sitemap couldn't fetch ERROR

Tags: asp.net, xml, sitemap

I have an asp.net web form project.
For creating a sitemap on this project i did n't use regular asp.net  `Web.sitemap` file in Visual Studio.

> menu File --> New File --> Web.sitemap from Visual Studio.

Instead i used the web site below for creating sitemap :
https://www.xml-sitemaps.com

Here is my created sitemap :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<!-- created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com -->


<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>1.00</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/Shop.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/Default.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/Activate_Your_Cards.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/Check_Card_Balance.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/How_To_Buy_Bitcoin_With_CoinMama_Worldwide.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/How_To_Buy_Bitcoin_In_Less_Than_5_Minutes.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/What_Is_Escrow_Protection_How_Does_Escrow_Work.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/Our_Team.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/About_VirtualVisaCards_Site.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/Where_To_Use_Virtual_Visa_Cards.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/Privacy_Policy.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/Term_Of_Service.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/FAQs.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/Contact_Us.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/Products/Silver_Virtual_Visa_Card.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/Products/Gold_Virtual_Visa_Card.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/Products/Platinum_Virtual_Visa_Card.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/billionaire_mark_cuban_i_see_gold_and_bitcoin_as_being_the_same_thing.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/what_are_virtual_credit_cards_and_should_you_have_one.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/stay_secure_online_with_virtual_credit_card_numbers.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/credit_not_as_great_as_you_would_like.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/all_you_want_to_know_about_emv_chip_cards.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/want_something_secured.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/CheckOut.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.64</priority>
</url>


</urlset>
```

And here you can validate my sitemap :
https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/validate-xml-sitemap.html
My sitemap link :
https://mysite.info/sitemap.xml
You can see everything is ok about my sitemap.
Now when i introduce my sitemap to `google search console` it tells :

> couldn't fetch

[image: couldn't fetch sitemap - google search console error]
Is this a google bug?
What did i do wrong & how can i fix this error?
For multiple sites i got this error.

---

**PS :**
For another web site i have this issue too.
I wait 1 month - but error is still there.

---

**Edit after comments :**
i cleared iis logs & here is the log after introduce my sitemap to google.

> Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5
>   Version: 1.0
>   Date: 2020-01-12 15:35:16
>   Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status
>   time-taken 2020-01-12 15:35:16 176.9.199.136 GET /sitemap.xml - 80 -
>   172.68.51.35 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+Win64;+x64;+rv:71.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/71.0
>   304 0 0 78 2020-01-12 15:35:27 176.9.199.136 GET /sitemap.xml - 80 -
>   141.101.99.168 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+XML+Sitemaps+Generator;+www.xml-sitemaps.com)+Gecko+XML-Sitemaps/1.0
>   200 0 0 33

As you see google did n't make a request to my machine at all.
I am so confused about that.

Comment: I think it may contain hidden carriage returns... try copying into Notepad first, then into your project? Also, check this: https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/3280971?hl=en

Comment: Is there any entry in the IIS log for when Google tries to fetch it? If so, did it give a 200 status code or something else?

Comment: @Andrew Morton if there is an iis issue why xml-sitemaps.com can validate my sitemap?

Comment: @Andrew Morton google recognized my TXT DNS record & let me in to my panel. So it should n't be DNS issue.

Comment: @IrishChieftain  I saw your link. "Yes, know there is a problem with the dashboard. Been telling Google about it for over a year.  Alas Googe seem uninterested in fixing it." > What is this mean? Is that a google bug?

Comment: @IrishChieftain i tried to copy sitemap to Notepad first. then added to my project. google still could n't fetch it. So crazy about that.

Comment: The sitemap is not required for a search engine to index the site. Is there any evidence that it has indexed some pages already, for example under the "Coverage" subsection of "Index"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about programming but it would fit on [Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Andrew Morton it's related to asp.net. Why vote to close man? It's so important for every body.

Comment: @SilverLight It is purely coincidence that the site runs on ASP.NET on IIS. Google has nothing against it. The people over on Pro Webmasters will be more familiar with this problem so you are likely to get a good answer there.

Comment: @Andrew Morton where should i ask such this question?

Comment: @SilverLight Over on [Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/). You can use the "flag" link under your question to ask a moderator to move it there for you if you like.

Comment: @SilverLight did you find any solution for this ?